# Emacs auto-complete installed by Package from http://marmalade-repo.org/ doesn't work

Tags: emacs, autocomplete, elisp, marmalade, emacs24

I'm new to Emacs and the version is 24.

As mentioned in the title, I've installed auto-complete by `M-x package-install` from [Marmalade-repo](http://marmalade-repo.org/), and the files lies in `~/.emacs.d/elpa/auto-complete-1.4/`.

Then I turned Emacs off and opened a new frame, but nothing happens when coding.

Do I need some configuration to make it run?

Comment: I have the same problem. Apparently auto-complete-mode does not get loaded. I have to enter (require 'auto-complete) in order to turn it on, and if I had this code to my .emacs it does not run.

Answer (score 4):

I had this same issue.
I fixed it by appending this to my .emacs

[/auto-complete/manual.html#Manual_Installation](http://auto-complete.org/doc/manual.html#manual-installation)

```
(add-to-list 'ac-dictionary-directories "~/.emacs.d/dict")
(require 'auto-complete-config)
(ac-config-default)
```

Comment: or, of course, something like `"~/.emacs.d/elpa/auto-complete-1.4/dict"`. and `(require 'auto-complete-config)` may need to come first.

Comment: I think the first line (`add-to-list`) is not needed - after installing auto-complete from marmalade, when I check the value of `ac-dictionary-directories` (using `C-h v`) it already has `~/.emacs.d/elpa/auto-complete-1.4/dict`

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem.  I tried what was suggested in the docs (and by elviejo), but that didn't work.  I then tried to do what Pedro suggested, which did work :-)  The code added to my init.el file is:

```
(require 'auto-complete)
(add-to-list 'ac-dictionary-directories "~/.emacs.d/ac-dict")
(require 'auto-complete-config)
(ac-config-default)
```

Comment: `(require 'auto-complete)` appeared to be mandatory on __OS X__ with __Emacs 24__

Comment: @Geradlus_RU it appeared to NOT be mandatory on OSX with emacs 24 for me

Answer (score 0):

I installed the Auto-Complete which hosted on the [github repo](https://github.com/m2ym/auto-complete).
But the installation should resemble that installed by Package.

It seems that u forgot to turn the auto-complete-mode on. Add follow fragment to your .emacs.d file and have a try.

```
(ac-config-default)
```

Comment: ~/.emacs or ~/.emacs.d/init.el